# Remove leading and trailing spaces with Find on OSX

Tags: macos, regex, find

I am trying to remove the leading and trailing spaces for filenames in user Home Folders on OSX. 
I have the the regular expression I need to find the leading and trailing spaces.

```
 ^[ ]+|[ ]+$
```

Im stuck trying to figure out how to incorporate this syntax with the Find command on OSX

Comment: On osx you need to tell it to use regex

Comment: Hi Im aware of that, Ive tried find $HOME -E -regex '^[ ]+|[ ]+$' but this isnt working

Comment: Expanding on your and @Raystafarian's comments, you probably need to add `-regextype posix-egrep` to the `find` command if you want to use `+` or `|` in the match. Another, possibly simpler answer is to let `find` do the ORring, as in `find -name " *" -or -name "* "`.

Comment: Note that you don't need to use `+`: any file name which begins with a space implicitly starts with one or more spaces, and similarly for ending with a space.

Comment: `\s` means whitespace in regexes as well, avoids having to type them out as sets

Answer (score 0):

Is this the desired behavior that you're looking for? Skip the regex.

```
$ touch 'nospace' 'spaces within' ' spaceatbeginning' 'spaceatend ' ' spaces within and at start and end '

$ find . \( -name ' *' -o -name '* ' \)
./ spaceatbeginning
./ spaces within and at start and end
./spaceatend
```